# How to make the size of icon consistent when using Shiny and Shinydashboard?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyalert

I am adding clickable icons in my shiny app to show a popup information box. Please see the following screenshot and code example. My strategy is to wrap my text and the code for `actionLink` in the `HTML` function. This works well. However, the size of the icon is determined by the size of the associated. I would like to know if it is possible to make all the icons the same size, such as the smallest one associated with the `selectInput`?

The documentation (https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.1/icon.html) mentioned that it is to set `"fa-3x"` in the `icon` function to make the size to be 3 times as normal. But in my case the size would sill be determined by the associated text and each text has a different size. So I guess this strategy would not work. It would be great if anyone can share their ideas or suggestions.

[image]

```
# Load the packages
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyalert)

# User Interface
ui <- dashboardPage(
  header = dashboardHeader(title = ""),
  sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem(
        text = "Example",
        tabName = "tab1"
      )
    )
  ),
  body = dashboardBody(
    # A call to use the shinyalert package
    useShinyalert(),

    tabItems(
      tabItem(
        tabName = "tab1",
        h2(HTML("This is a title",
           as.character(actionLink(inputId = "info1", 
                                   label = "", 
                                   icon = icon("info"))))),
        fluidRow(
          box(
            title = HTML("This is the title of the box",
                         as.character(actionLink(inputId = "info2", 
                                                 label = "", 
                                                 icon = icon("info")))), 
            status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE,
            selectInput(inputId = "Select", 
                        label = HTML("This is the title of the selectInput",
                                     as.character(actionLink(inputId = "info3", 
                                                             label = "", 
                                                             icon = icon("info")))), 
                        choices = 1:3)
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  observeEvent(input$info1, {
    shinyalert(text = "Info 1", type = "info")
  })
  observeEvent(input$info2, {
    shinyalert(text = "Info 2", type = "info")
  })
  observeEvent(input$info3, {
    shinyalert(text = "Info 3", type = "info")
  })
}

# Run the app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly but if you want the them all to have the same size you can adapt the font size for the icons like this:

```
# Load the packages
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyalert)

# User Interface
ui <- dashboardPage(
  header = dashboardHeader(title = ""),
  sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem(
        text = "Example",
        tabName = "tab1"
      )
    )
  ),
  body = dashboardBody(
    # A call to use the shinyalert package
    useShinyalert(),

    tabItems(
      tabItem(
        tabName = "tab1",
        h2(HTML("This is a title", "<font size='3'>",
                as.character(actionLink(inputId = "info1", 
                                        label = "", 
                                        icon = icon("info"))), "</font>")),
        fluidRow(
          box(
            title = HTML("This is the title of the box", "<font size='3'>",
                         as.character(actionLink(inputId = "info2", 
                                                 label = "", 
                                                 icon = icon("info"))), "</font>"), 
            status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE,
            selectInput(inputId = "Select", 
                        label = HTML("This is the title of the selectInput", "<font size='3'>", as.character(actionLink(inputId = "info3", 
                                                                                                                   label = "", 
                                                                                                                   icon = icon("info"))), "</font>"
                                     ), 
                        choices = 1:3)
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  observeEvent(input$info1, {
    shinyalert(text = "Info 1", type = "info")
  })
  observeEvent(input$info2, {
    shinyalert(text = "Info 2", type = "info")
  })
  observeEvent(input$info3, {
    shinyalert(text = "Info 3", type = "info")
  })
}

# Run the app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Good answer. Thanks. This is exactly what I want, which is controlling the size of the icon no matter what the size of the associated text is.